# What is a good function to map an id to memcache in a pool of servers?

Tags: python, memcached

Something like:

```
host = getHost(id)
>>> 172.16.25.52
```

Ideally, the algorithm should minimize the number of cache misses when the pool of servers is expanded / contracted.

Are there any known algorithms out there that do this?  Or libraries, potentially (I'm using Python).

Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe what you're asking more clearly and completely?

Comment: Hi -- Sorry.  What I mean is, if I have N servers, and I expand my pool to N+X servers, I'm going to have cache misses because the cache will have to rebuild on the new servers.  Is there an algorithm that will allow me to expand my pool of servers while minimizing the number of cache misses?

Answer (score 1):

The memcached library does this by default. So you can just read the code from the repository: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-memcached-team/python-memcached/trunk/annotate/head%3A/memcache.py#L274

As for minimizing the cache misses with an expanding/contracting pool... a difficult thing to do. Either you're not dividing the servers correctly at first or it will be less optimal when expanding/contracting. If you would have a maximum of N servers than it might be easier though, since you can make a couple of assumptions.

Comment: I thought memcached did this by default, and so that's why the question confused me.